# How does the new Data Extract interface compare to the old one?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract

I am trying to perform a data extract via the new "lightning enabled interface" in Automation Studio.

I have the configuration below, but it keeps erroring.

[image]

I have searched for documentation, but can only find the ones for Email Studio, which I assume will be deprecated in the near future.

I will appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the new Activities can be found here under Automation Studio:

[**Data Extract Activity**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/)

If you hover over the step that failed in Automation Studio, it'll likely give you a clue as to what failed.